# Get Incoming File Transfer Status in Python

Tags: python, networking, ubuntu-12.04, samba

Tried the googles already to no avail.

**The situation:** I have a home server/NAS/machine which does all kinds of things. There's an LCD panel build into the case which cycles through all kind of useful info (CPU, Mem, HD health etc.). I'm using a python script to query and output this info the LCD panel appropriately.

**Want I want to achieve:** I want to add a feature so that when file are being transferred to the server (SAMBA), the python script outputs the status (like you would see in windows file tranfer, number of files remaining, % etc.) to the LCD.

So I'm wondering how can I use python to get the details (if any) of incoming SAMBA (or whatever else) file transfers? I mean - is this even doable?

**Side note** - the server is running Ubuntu 12.04 - so any other suitable non python solution would work, I'm sure could just parse the data to my script one way or another.

Thanks in advance stackers!